# zookeeper queue delay?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, beanstalkd

What would you guys suggest to be a good way to implement a queue in zookeeper that has the ability to delay a job without blocking a worker?

Reference beanstalkd delayed job option.

Comment: What do you mean by `delay a job without blocking a worker`?

Comment: Meaning that I don't want a worker, taking the job off the queue and sleeping for lets say an hour until it starts processing the job

Answer (score 0):

What you need is develop a Barriers using zookeeper.

I assume the "delay time" was set by another process called master.

Master first create a node say /work/flag with data "false"

What worker need to do is get and watch node /work/flag. The watcher would call back in asyn so you can do other thing in worker, would't block.

When the time comes, master would set the /work/flag data to "true", which cause a ZOO_CHANGED_EVENT event.

And the worker should get the event call back saying "ZOO_CHANGED_EVENT" in /work/flag. Then it can get and check if /work/flag is true and determine whether continue the workflow.